# Como gerar um APK sem DEBUG no IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, apk, intellij-idea

Acabei de migrar meus projetos do Eclipse para o *IntelliJ IDEA* (é o mesmo que o AndroidStudio usa, mas com algumas diferenças pequenas).

Todavia toda vez que clico em <kbd>Build</kbd> > <kbd>Build Apk</kbd> ele gera um APK com "debug ativado".

Pelo que andei lendo a propriedade `android:debuggable="true"` não é suportada desde 2010.

Como posso gerar o APK?

Comment: Posso estar enganado (ou não), mas acho que o modo "não debugger" é apenas quando o app está assinado, que daí você tem um .apk para mandar para a play store. Você não consegue mandar um app não assinado (que dai ele está como debugger).

Ps.: Como você sabe que tá como debug ativo?

Comment: @CarlosBridi não tenho certeza mas eu penso que seja isso porque ele gera dois arquivos assim `app-debug.apk` e `app-debug-unaligned.apk`, como eu fiz esse app pra uso da empresa eu não posso disponibilizar na playstore :/

Comment: Se você for em Build, vai ter duas opções: Build APK e uma Generated Signed APK. Você pode gerar uma assinatura para você ter na empresa (e associar ela ao seu projeto lá em Project Strucutre > Aba Signing - adicione uma nova), impedindo que outras pessoas gerem uma apk de produção sem tua autorização (ou de quem tiver a senha) e testar se vai gerar um apk sem o debug mode.

Comment: Ps.: Vou postar como resposta, se realmente for, me avise, caso não dai removo a resposta

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o modo "não debugger" é apenas quando o app está assinado, que daí você tem um .apk para mandar para a play store. Você não consegue mandar um app para a loja sem ele estar assinado (que dai ele está como debugger).

Crie uma assinatura para ele e associe ao projeto lá em:

Botão direito no Projeto:

```
Open Module Settings > Signing
```

Adicione uma assinatura e link o arquivo .jks nesse momento seu projeto vai estar assinado e você pode liberar aos usuários, para voltar ao desenvolvimento, remova a assinatura e mais tarde ligue-a novamente, quando for soltar uma nova realese.

Comment: Obrigado, já vou testar, assim que o update dos pacotes no sdk terminar :)